# Phaser JS - Adding a new child to a group stops every other child from moving

Tags: javascript, grouping, children, phaser-framework

I have a Phaser group:

```
enemies = game.add.group();
```

I am adding children to the group the following way:

```
enemies.add(game.add.sprite(1100,30,"unit"));
```

and then moving them like this:

```
enemies.subAll('x', 3);
```

Everything is moving fine until I add a new child and then all previous ones just stop.

I've been struggling with this for 2 hours now. I think the children are overwritten when I add a new one but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the group was created within the function that adds multiple children to it, thus it is reset every time the function is called. Moving `enemies = game.add.group();` outside the function solves the problem.